# Prove inequalities using MVT: $(1+h)^\alpha \leq 1+\alpha h$ and $b^{\frac1n} -a^{\frac1n}\ <(b-a)^{\frac1n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

Use MVT to prove the following inequalities :

(1) let $0< \alpha\leq1 \ $ and $h \geq -1$, then

$$(1+h)^\alpha \ \leq 1+\alpha h$$

(2) let $0<a<b$, show that $$b^{\frac{1}{n}} \ -a^{\frac{1}{n}} \ <(b-a)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

In both of these problems what should be our function $f$ and corresponding closed interval. any hint.

thanks in advance

Comment: prepare to waste a few sheets of paper, and stare at MVT. In particular, try applying MVT to some of your favourite functions, like polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $k = 1+h$, then $k \ge 0$, and we prove:

$f(k)= k^{\alpha} -1 -\alpha(k-1)\le 0$ which is a bit easier to digest than proving the original one. Observe $f(1) = 0$, thus we consider $k \neq 1$,and assume WLOG that $k > 1$. On $[1,k]$ we have by MVT that: $f(k) - f(1) = (k-1)f'(c)$. And $f'(c) = \alpha c^{\alpha -1}-\alpha= \alpha(c^{\alpha - 1} - 1)< 0$ since $1 < c$, and $\alpha \le 1$. Thus $f'(c) < 0$, and it follows that $f(k) < f(1) = 0$ and this is the inequality you want to verify.

For the second inequality, consider $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{a}-\sqrt[n]{x-a}$ defined over $[a,x]$. Using MVT theorem we have: $f(b) - f(a) = (b-a)f'(c)\implies f(b) = \dfrac{b-a}{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{c^{n-1}}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(c-a)^{n-1}}}\right)< 0$ since $c > c -a > 0$. Thus $f(b) < f(a) = 0$, and this implies the inequality to be true.